# JUnit Testing EJB layer with embedded glassfish and Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, glassfish, ejb

I have an existing JEE Maven and Eclipse project:

```
mainProject.ear
+--project1.war
+--project2.war
+--ejb-proj.jar
```

I would like to have a test profile for unit testing the EJB project, including read/write database with JPA.

I have added a dependency in my `pom.xml` like this:

```
        <!-- Embedded glassfish -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-74b</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>embedded-glassfish</goalPrefix>
                <port>8080</port>
                <autoDelete>true</autoDelete>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.44</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

Then I have created a test class:

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    // instantiate container and context
    ejbContainer = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer();
    logger.info("Opening the container");
    ctx = ejbContainer.getContext();
}
```

These are the Maven goals, in Eclipse "skip test" is unflagged:

```
clean compile package
```

Glassfish is correctly started but I get an error about missing jdbc driver.

```
Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
```

So, these are the questions:

1. Why is the mysql dependency in embedded glassfish ignored ?
2. Is it correct to start the embedded container from the test class ? Maybe it would be better to have it started during the test phases.
3. In the end I want the container to be initialized only for the ejb test, so I suppose I have to deploy the ejb jar only. How can I do that ?

For completeness, the same maven goals with `skip test = true` just work. And the .ear deployed in a running container works too.

Comment: I admit, I don't know much about embedded glassfish, but I think you will need the embedded maria-db as well. You could also try h2 instead, that works in memory and initializes easily for each test method. Or another alternative to develop TDD-oriented EJB is [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit)